# A more elegant way to display null?

Tags: c#, nullable

I have a (probably) dumb question about display formatting of nullable types. At the moment, when I need to indicate that a field of a nullable type does indeed have a null value, I code it like this:

```
var stringToDisplay = nullableDecimal.HasValue ? nullableDecimal.ToString() : "N/A";
```

Or some variation of that basic text.

I don't think I can use a coalesce operator - or at least I don't think that's the right approach (correct me if I'm wrong).

Is there a better and more efficient way to do this? I just feel like this boilerplate code is infesting my codebase more and more these days...

Comment: Why not a generic extension method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your approach isn't bad per se, but you are right about your worry for code duplication. You can solve this by creating an auxiliary method, such as:

```
public static class DecimalExtensions
{
    public static string Display(this decimal? value) 
    {
        return value.HasValue ? value.ToString(): "N/A";
    }
}
```

In this example I have created an extension method but a regular method would also work just fine. Then you can do just:

```
var stringToDisplay = nullableDecimal.Display();
```

...which is nicer to read and prevents the myriad of "N/A"s in the code (and as stated in the comments, also eases refactoring if ever needed).

Comment: I was just typing up something almost exactly the same, on the plus side, it gives you a single place that you have to change the "N/A" string if you need to refactor it to say something else, like "None".

Comment: Spelling mistake: DecimalExtenstions should be DecimalExtensions.

Answer (score 10):

In C# 5 or older your code is probably as good as it gets, though you could always extract that out to its own method if you have sprinkled it all over the place.

Also consider stuffing `"N/A"` into a constant, in case you want to change it.

However, in C# 6 you can change it somewhat, although it won't get *much* better:

```
var stringToDisplay = nullableDecimal?.ToString() ?? "N/A";
```

The `?.` operator is called the "null-conditional" operator and is basically a short syntax for the expression you had to begin with.

Basically, that part of the expression means this:

```
string temp = nullableDecimal != null ? nullableDecimal.ToString() : null;
```

although the `?.` operator would only evaluate the part before it once, not twice, so it's more like this:

```
var operand = nullableDecimal;
string temp = operand != null ? operand.ToString() : null;
```

Not really important here though, but if it was a method call, it might be.

As for extracting it into a method, simply create an extension method:

```
public static class MyNullableDecimalExtensions
{
    public static string ToDisplayText(this decimal? value)
    {
        if (decimal.HasValue)
            return decimal.Value.ToString();
        return "N/A";
    }
}
```

I'm not overly fond of the `?:` operator syntax, so in a method like this I would write out the full if-statement instead.

Then you could call it like this:

```
var stringToDisplay = nullableDecimal.ToDisplayText();
```

Comment: if I could accept both yours and Konamiman's answers, I would! Thanks for the guidance from you both - I ended up using parts of both answers, with much pleasure.